# Adding a percentage of group column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a pivot table in a data frame and I'd like calculate group percentages.

for example:
[image: Sample pivot data]

and what I need is:
[image: desired output]

I've exluded the original data but I'd expect to have that and I know I need to add in these columns.

If I need to add totals to do this that's fine as well, as I will be filtering results out later anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not really show what is in your index and not.

I made my own dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':["NL"]*9, 'team':["A"]*3+["B"]*3+["C"]*3, 'outcome':["WIN", "LOSE", "DRAW"] * 3, 'week1':[2,3,4,4,5,2,4,4,2], 'week2':[3,2,5,2,3,4,2,3,4], 'week3':[4,5,2,3,2,5,3,2,5]})
df.set_index(['country', 'team'], inplace=True)
```

Note that i made a Team C as well. Since two team B does not make sense. I assumed it was a mistake.

By my example, you can simply do:

```
df_percent = df / df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
df_percent['outcome'] = df['outcome']

             outcome     week1     week2     week3
country team                                      
NL      A        WIN  0.222222  0.300000  0.363636
        A       LOSE  0.333333  0.200000  0.454545
        A       DRAW  0.444444  0.500000  0.181818
        B        WIN  0.363636  0.222222  0.300000
        B       LOSE  0.454545  0.333333  0.200000
        B       DRAW  0.181818  0.444444  0.500000
        C        WIN  0.400000  0.222222  0.300000
        C       LOSE  0.400000  0.333333  0.200000
        C       DRAW  0.200000  0.444444  0.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide the dataframe by sum of the number of games per country and team, obtained using `groupby` and reshaped using `transform`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ["NL"] * 9, 
                   'team': ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3 + ["C"] * 3, 
                   'outcome': ["WIN", "LOSE", "DRAW"] * 3, 
                   'week1': [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2], 
                   'week2': [3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'week3': [4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 5]})
df.set_index(['country', 'team', 'outcome'], inplace=True)

>>> df.divide(df.reset_index().groupby(['country', 'team']).transform(sum).values)
                         week1     week2     week3
country team outcome                              
NL      A    WIN      0.222222  0.300000  0.363636
             LOSE     0.333333  0.200000  0.454545
             DRAW     0.444444  0.500000  0.181818
        B    WIN      0.363636  0.222222  0.300000
             LOSE     0.454545  0.333333  0.200000
             DRAW     0.181818  0.444444  0.500000
        C    WIN      0.400000  0.222222  0.300000
             LOSE     0.400000  0.333333  0.200000
             DRAW     0.200000  0.444444  0.500000
```

To make this more clear, you can see what `transform` is doing.  It returns the results in the same shape as the original dataframe.

```
>>> df.reset_index().groupby(['country', 'team']).transform(sum).values
array([[ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [11,  9, 10],
       [11,  9, 10],
       [11,  9, 10],
       [10,  9, 10],
       [10,  9, 10],
       [10,  9, 10]])
```

You can also use `transform` in the method proposed by @firelynx and skip his last step:

```
>>> df.divide(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform(sum))

                         week1     week2     week3
country team outcome                              
NL      A    WIN      0.222222  0.300000  0.363636
             LOSE     0.333333  0.200000  0.454545
             DRAW     0.444444  0.500000  0.181818
        B    WIN      0.363636  0.222222  0.300000
             LOSE     0.454545  0.333333  0.200000
             DRAW     0.181818  0.444444  0.500000
        C    WIN      0.400000  0.222222  0.300000
             LOSE     0.400000  0.333333  0.200000
             DRAW     0.200000  0.444444  0.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you just wanted to add percentage symbol to all those three columns, considering it a dataframe. if yes you can use the below

```
df.week1 = df.week1.astype(str).add('%')
df.week2 = df.week2.astype(str).add('%')
df.week3 = df.week3.astype(str).add('%')
```